# Python/C++, PyQt4/Qt4: How to insert multiple lines text into a cell in QTextTable

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qtextdocument, qtextcursor

I'm trying to create a odt document by using PyQt4. The document involves inserting multiple lines text into cells. My example code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
cur = QtGui.QTextCursor(doc)
table = cur.insertTable(1, 2)
# The cursor is moved to the first cell of the table
cur.insertText("""line 1
line 2""")

writer = QtGui.QTextDocumentWriter()
writer.setFormat(writer.supportedDocumentFormats()[1]) # ODF Format
writer.setFileName('example.odt')
writer.write(doc)
```

I want 'line 1' and 'line 2' to be in the same cell, but they are in different cells due to the line break. This also had the same effect as the code above:

```
cur.insertText('line 1\n')
cur.insertText('line 2\n')
```

Comment: Faced with this problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @zaurilla It was a long time ago. I can not remember whether I solved this problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it’s too late.

If you use chr(10) you insert a line feed. There are two ways to do it.

```
cur.insertText(‘line1’)
cur.insertText(chr(10))
cur.insertText(‘line2’+chr(10))
cur.insertText(‘line3’)
```